# A trouble regarding the data binding of the SelectedItem of a custom ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, dependency-properties, selecteditem

I have a custom StringListView as shown below, but the data binding of the SelectedItem does not correctly work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="hogeWPF2.StringListView">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
                SelectionMode="Single" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>                      
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class StringListView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PersonsSource", typeof (ObservableCollection<Person>), typeof (StringListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<Person>)));

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Person>) GetValue(PersonsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPersonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedPerson", typeof (Person), typeof (StringListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(Person)));

    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return (Person) GetValue(SelectedPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedPersonProperty, value); }
    }

    public StringListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow, I put my custom ListView as follows.

```
<Window x:Class="hogeWPF2.MainWindow">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
        <local:StringListView PersonsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedPerson="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
        private set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person{ Age = 25},
            new Person{ Age = 30},
            new Person{ Age = 35},
        };
    }
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't use my custom StringListView and instead directly write the contents of it in XAML of the MainWindow, the SelectedItem is correctly recognized. However, if I use my custom StringListView, the data binding fails to work and the SelectedItem seems to be always null. I guess the root cause exists in the Dependency Property SelectedPerson in StringListView class, since there happen no errors if I don't use it. But I don't understand how to revise it. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: It is bad practice binding user control to itself. You window/grid binding doesn't inherited by user control.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But could you tell me in further detail what you exactly mean by "binding user control to itself"?

Comment: I resolved this problem by setting the binding mode of  SelectedItem to TwoWay.